# how to add register form code in existing upload image

Tags: php

This is my code:

```
     <html>
<head>
<title>upload images to database</title>
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/style.css">
</head>
<body>
<h1>Register Form</h1>
<form class = "form" action="backup.php" method = "POST" enctype = "multipart/form-data">
Upload Photo:<input type= "file" name= "image"><br />
Firstname:<input type = "text" name = "fname"><br />
Lastname:<input type = "text" name = "lname"><br />
Password:<input type = "text" name = "password"><br />
Retype-password:<input type = "text" name = "rpassword"><br />
Email:<input type = "text" name = "email"><br />
Address:<input type = "text" name = "address"><br />
Phone:<input type = "text" name = "phone"><br />
<input type= "submit" class = "submit" value= "upload">
</form>

<?php
if ($_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD'] == 'POST') {
//connect to database
mysql_connect("localhost","root","") or die(mysql_error());
mysql_select_db("image") or die(mysql_error());
$file = '';
$file= $_FILES['image']['tmp_name'];
$firstname = $_POST['fname'];
$lastname = $_POST['lname'];
$email = $_POST['email'];
$address = $_POST['address'];
$phone = $_POST['phone'];
$password = $_POST['password'];
$rpassword = $_POST['rpassword'];
 if(!isset($file))
 {
 echo "please select an image";
 }
 else
 {
$image = mysql_real_escape_string(file_get_contents($_FILES['image']['tmp_name']));
$image_name = mysql_real_escape_string($_FILES['image']['name']);
$image_size = getimagesize($_FILES['image']['tmp_name']);
if($image_size ==FALSE)
{
echo "That's not an image";
}
else
    {
    if(!$insert = mysql_query("INSERT INTO upload VALUES('','$image_name','$image','$firstname','$lastname','$email','$address','$password','$rpassword')"))
    {
    echo "Problem uploading image";
    }
    else{

    $lastid = mysql_insert_id();
    echo "Image upload.<p/>Your Image</p><img src=get.php?id=$lastid>";

    }
} 
 }
}
?>
</body>
</html>
```

This is my php code for upload image and stored in database and also displayed in home page.

Now it works fine, and i want to add code for extra fields such as first name,last name...etc like register form.

Here what i need to add code for register form.

Can anybody help me?

Comment: http://board.phpbuilder.com/showthread.php?10375514-RESOLVED-Add-image-upload-to-already-existing-form

Answer (score 0):

you should use $_POST method becouse you have `action="POST"` in your form html it sends data to server using post request

Add in html

```
<form action="index.php" method = "POST" enctype = "multipart/form-data">
    First Name: <input type = "text" name= "fname"><br />
    Last Name:<input type = "text" name= "lname"><br />
    Password :<input type = "text" name = "password"><br />
    Retype-password: <input type = "text" name = "rpassword"><br />
    Email:<input type = "text" name = "email"><br />
    Phone Num: <input type = "text" name = "phone"><br />
    Address: <input type ="text" name = "address"><br />
    ...... some your html 
</form>
```

Get data on server

```
$firstname = $_POST['fname'];
$lastname = $_POST['lname'];
$email = $_POST['email'];
$address = $_POST['address'];
$phone = $_POST['phone'];
$password = $_POST['password'];
$rpassword = $_POST['rpassword'];
```

### [**Look at this tutorial**](http://www.w3schools.com/php/php_forms.asp)

Comment: I already used, Still got error like undefined index.  I think need to add some other code. I don't know, what is the best way. Can help with my code?

Comment: I added as posted your code in my code, it displays undefined index index, in all lines.

Comment: look my updated answer if I understand correctly you interested in where to add html inputs ... in my answer bot side server and client is provided

Comment: Please check my updated post, and guide me, now it displayed problem loading image.